# Is there a method to upload batch file scripts into python(and be able to work with them)

Tags: python-3.x

Python has extended libraries and one of the most useful keywords in python is  `import`. Is there a way to upload batch file scripts into one of your libraries or Is there way to import them straight from batch file?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to run batch commands (or a batch script) through python?

Comment: Sorry, what are "batch file commands"?

Comment: Thank you for informing me, I mean batch file script, for example: echo, pause , start and .....

Comment: If they're not written in python, then no, you can't simply `import` them. Of course, if they are common utilities, you might be able to find an alternative written in python.

Comment: Thank you glibdud, So is there a way to add them in or to link them to python.